# Passing javascript variable to PHP using ajax but it gives error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to pass my JavaScript variable using Ajax into my PHP script but that doesn't work it given me error that it is undefined index. both codes are in different files but both of them are accessible on the main page.

Here's my script.php

```
<script>
function get_child_options(){
    var parentID = jQuery('#parent').val();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/**/**/**/child_categories.php', 
        type: 'POST',
        data: {parentID : parentID},
        success: function(data){
            jQuery('#child').html(data);
        },
        error: function(){alert("Something Went Wrong with child options. ")},
    });
}
jQuery('select[name="parent"]').change(get_child_options);
</script>
```

And this is my php file

```
<?php
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/ **/core/init.php';             //Including database path stored in init.php

$parentID = (int)$_POST['parentID'];
$childQuery = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent = '$parentID' ORDER BY category";

ob_start();
?>

<option value="">Select <strong>Child</strong> Category</option>
<?php while ($child = mysqli_fetch_assoc($childQuery)): ?>
    <option value="<?= $child['id']; ?>"><?= $child['category']; ?></option>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php
    echo ob_get_clean();
?>
```

in script the #parent is a form id i am passing to javascript using jQuery.

because of variable is not accessible PHP is not running query.

This is my products.php the main where page where this is happening

```
    <?php
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Online Store/core/init.php';           //Including database path stored in init.php
    include 'includes/head.php';                                                    //Including header
    include 'includes/navigation.php';                                              //Including Navigation bar
    include 'includes/script.php';                                              

    if (isset($_GET['add'])) {
        $brandQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM brand ORDER BY brand");
        $parentQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent = 0 ORDER BY category");

?>      
    <h2 class="text-center">Add A New Product</h2><hr />
    <form action="products.php?add=1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <label for="title">Title*:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" value="<?= ((isset($_POST['title']))?sanitize($_POST['title']):''); ?>" placeholder="Add a title" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <label for="brand">Brand*: </label>
            <select class="form-control ">
                <option value="" <?= ((isset($_POST['brand']) && $_POST['brand'] == '')?' selected':''); ?> >Select Brand</option>
                <?php while($brand = mysqli_fetch_assoc($brandQuery)): ?>
                    <option value="<?= $brand['id']; ?>" <?= ((isset($_POST['brand']) && $_POST['brand'] == $brand['id'])?' selected':''); ?> ><?= $brand['brand'] ?></option>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <label for="parent">Parent Category*: </label>
            <select class="form-control" id="parent" name="parent">
                <option value="" <?= ((isset($_POST['parent']) && $_POST['parent'] == '')?' select':''); ?> >Select <strong>Parent</strong> Category</option>
                <?php while($parent = mysqli_fetch_assoc($parentQuery)): ?>
                    <option value="<?= $parent['id']; ?>" <?= ((isset($_POST['parent']) && $_POST['parent'] == $parent['id'])?' select':''); ?> ><?= $parent['category']; ?></option>
                <?php endwhile; ?>  
            </select>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <label for="child">Child Category*: </label>
            <select id="child" name="child" class="form-control"></select>
            <?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Online Store/admin/parsers/child_categories.php'; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <label for="price">Price*: </label>
            <input type="text" id="price" name="price" class="form-control" value="<?= ((isset($_POST['price']))?sanitize($_POST['price']):''); ?>" />

        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <label for="list_price">List Price*: </label>
            <input type="text" id="list_price" name="list_price" class="form-control" value="<?= ((isset($_POST['list_price']))?sanitize($_POST['list_price']):''); ?>" />

        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <label>Quantity & Sizes</label>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-info form-control" onclick="jQuery('#sizesModal').modal('toggle'); return false;">Quantity & Sizes</button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <label for="sizes">Sizes & Quantity preview*: </label>
            <input type="text" name="sizes" id="sizes" class="form-control" value="<?= ((isset($_POST['sizes']))?$_POST['sizes']:''); ?>" readonly/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="photo">Photo*: </label>
            <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="description">Description</label>
            <textarea name="description" id="description" class="form-control" rows="6" placeholder="Description" ><?= ((isset($_POST['description']))?sanitize($_POST['description']):''); ?></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group pull-right">
        <input type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-success" value="Add Product" />
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </form>
<?php   
    }else{

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE deleted = 0";
    $presults = $db->query($sql);
    $product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($presults);

    // Featured product
    if (isset($_GET['featured'])) {
        $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
        $featured = (int)$_GET['featured'];
        $featuredSql = "UPDATE `products` SET `featured` = '$featured' WHERE `products`.`id` = '$product[id]' ";
        $db->query($featuredSql);
        // header('Location: products.php');
    }
?>

<h2 class="text-center">Products</h2>
<a href="products.php?add=1" class="btn btn-success pull-right" id="add-product-btn">Add Product</a><div class="clearfix"></div>
<hr />

<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">
    <thead>
        <th></th>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Featured</th>
        <th>Sold</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php 
            while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($presults)): 
                $childID = $product['categories'];
                $catSql = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = '$childID'";
                $result = $db->query($catSql);
                $child = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                $parentID = $child['parent'];
                $pSql = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = '$parentID'"; 
                $presult = $db->query($pSql);
                $parent = mysqli_fetch_assoc($presult);
                $category = $parent['category'].'~'.$child['category'];
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="products.php?edit=<?= $product['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-default"><span class= " glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
                    <a href="products.php?delete=<?= $product['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-default"><span class= " glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span></a>

                </td>
                <td><?= $product['title']; ?></td>
                <td><?= money($product['price']) ?></td>
                <td><?= $category; ?></td>
                <td><a href="products.php?featured=<?= (($product['featured'] == 0)?'1':'0'); ?>&id =<?= $product['id']; ?>" class=" btn btn-sx btn-default">
                    <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-<?= (($product['featured'] == 1)?'minus':'plus'); ?>"></span>

                </a>&nbsp <?= (($product['featured'] == 1)?'Featured':''); ?></td>
                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
        <?php endwhile; ?>  
    </tbody>
</table>

<?php
}
    include 'includes/footer.php';                                                  //Including footer

?>
```

Is there any other way to do it? What I am trying to do is when user selects parent category I want child category to arrange as per parent category.

Comment: are you sure the ajax is passed?can you share the html to show the element with the id parent

Comment: are you using core php or framework??

Comment: #parent id must be of select not form id can share html for more information

Comment: i have updated html page

Comment: What is the full text of the "undefined index" message?

Comment: +darwin von corax Notice: Undefined index: parentID in C:\xampp\htdocs\Online Store\admin\parsers\child_categories.php on line 4
Select Child Category 
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Online Store\admin\parsers\child_categories.php on line 11

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
function get_child_options(){
    var parentID = $(this).val();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/**/**/**/child_categories.php', 
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'parentID' : parentID},
        success: function(data){
            jQuery('#child').html(data);
        },
        error: function(){alert("Something Went Wrong with child options. ")},
    });
}
jQuery('select[name="parent"]').change(get_child_options);
</script>
```

Getting the Value by $(this) and putting single quotes around parentID `data: {'parentID' : parentID},`

Comment: No nothing happened. i did exactly as you said. still there is error.